# vba Active Input Box- Open new excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a vba program, wherein an input box is active. A data has to be checked in another excel file which needs to be filled in input box. Since the input box is active, I can't open or activate another excel file. Please help.

Comment: what kind of `inputbox` you use? you could try to use `textbox on UserForm` to simulate `inputbox` showed with `vbModeless` parameter.

Comment: The command I am using is

Comment: Set mdlf = Workbooks.Open(filetopen2)
mdlrow = InputBox("Enter the Row Number of DCC in MDL code to be Placed in SAP= ", "Row Number", 2)

Comment: as suggested- use `UserForm` with `TextBox` on it showed in `vbModeless` state

Answer (score 0):

Since the input box is a modal dialog, Excel has control of it until its OK button is activated. You will need to either find a way to gather the information before you display the input box, or add it after it is processed.

A third, rather complex alternative is to have another process that watches for the input box, gets the information from the other book, and pastes it into the box. This is the domain of such tools as WinBatch, which I have used from time to time to perform such tasks. Other tools exist, as well, most notably, AutoIT, which is functionally and otherwise very similar to WinBatch.